# Submit textarea on enter

Tags: textarea, submit, form-submit

I found many solutions.  But not the right one.  I don't know if this is accurate, but I read only 2% of users have javascript enabled.  I'm trying to stay away from javascript the best I can.  Is there a way to submit textarea on enter without javascript?  Much help is greatly appreciated.  Thank You!

Comment: 2% of users have javascript DISabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478737/browser-statistics-on-javascript-disabled

Comment: lol.  really?  Must've been an old article.  I know they said enabled.  It was an article on why not to use javascript.  Probably old article.  Well, thanks for the information.  Maybe I'll use javascript more :)

Comment: I was successfully able to replace textarea with input type text, is there a reason why I shouldn't use text input type for long paragraphs?  If not, it's working fine, I think I can stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already asked this here:
[Submit Form Without Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788956/submit-form-without-javascript)

Also, you have it backwards; 2% of users have it disabled. While it is good to have fallbacks for JS-disabled users, don't stay away of JS. If you're working on the web, you pretty much have to use JS.